# I am interested in what n*log(N) Big O looks like

Tags: c, time-complexity, big-o

I know that simple linear Big O looks like this (it's all in C):

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main()
{
    int array[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}; //elements of the array
    int a; //creating the new variables
    for (a=0;a<10;a++){
            printf("%d\n", array[a]); //print elements of the array

    }
}
```

And I know that N^2 Big O looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
int main()
{
    int array[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}; //elements of the array
    int a,b; //creating the two variables
    for (a=0;a<10;a++){ //do stuff
        for (b=0;b<10;b++){ //do stuff
            printf("%d = %d\n", array[a],array[b]); //print elements of the array
        }
    }
}
```

What I am interested in is what n*log(n) Big O looks like.

Comment: Look at a [mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's log base 2, then dividing `n` by half repeatedly until it reaches 1 is the most typical way to capture a log(n) complexity:

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2);
```

So O(n log(n)) would look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (int j = n; j > 0; j /= 2) {
    // O(1) work
  }
}
```

Conceptually, this is like running a binary search (O(log(n)) for every element of an array (O(n)).

[Merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) is a [typical O(n log(n)) algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm)--the log(n) part is splitting up the array into chunks and the O(n) part is merging the chunks back together. For every O(log(n)) split operation, an O(n) merge occurs so the complexities are multiplied together as in a nested loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The 'log-n' factor is added by taking Divide and Conquer into account. Some of those algorithms are the best designed and often used.

1. Merge Sort
2. Heap Sort
3. Quick Sort
4. Certain Divide and Conquer Algorithms based on optimizing O(n^2) algorithms